# Pig case statement for finding no. Of events in a specific period of time

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Pig case statement for finding no. Of events in a specific period of time.

There is a dataset which is like a movie data base bearing movies, rating, duration of movie, year of release.
The question is that how do u find the no. Of movies released during 10 years of span?
The dataset is comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

```
year_count = FOREACH movie GENERATE (case when year>2000 and year<2010 then 1 else 0 end) as year_flag,movie_name;
year_grp = GROUP year_count BY year_flag;
movie_count_out = FOREACH year_grp GENERATE group,COUNT(year_flag);
```

The above example can help you give an understanding of the solution, there might be some syntax errors tough. If you need to group on the basis of decade then you can use a substring function on top of year and get the specific range.

Comment: Abhi thank you for the help. I am getting an error I.e  mismatched input can you help me with that.

Comment: ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 102>  mismatched input ')' expecting END

Failed to parse: <line 1, column 102>  mismatched input ')' expecting END

Comment: End was missing in case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Movie = load '/home/movie/movies.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (movieid:int, moviename:chararray, yearrelease:int, ratingofmovie:float, moviedurationinsec:float);

movies_released_between_2000_2010 = filter Movie by yearofrelease >2000 and yearofrelease < 2010;

result = foreach movies_released_between_2000_2010 generate moviename,yearofrelease;

dump result;